# How do I get rid of white border around youtube video embedded in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

In my iPad application I have a UIWebView with a youtube video embedded in it. I have matched the UIWebView size and the size of the embedded video as well as made sure that the aspect ratio was correct. I have set the UIWebView background color to clear color with no luck. How can I center the embedded video inside my UIWebView. I also used content mode: center and it doesn't seem to respect it. See the screenshot below:

http://cl.ly/1N3c0d343r3v1i0J1h0d

```
NSString *video_ID = @"7Ek1QwGp9Tw?rel=0";

NSString *htmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"453\" height=\"255\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>",video_ID];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

just a wild guess: you need to reset the margins and paddings of your html documents body and the youtube iframe.

edit add something like `<html><head><title>.</title><style>body,html,iframe{margin:0;padding:0;}</style></head><body>[YOUR YOUTUBE CODE]</body></html>`

Comment: looks like your html string got lost in translation

Comment: I fixed it. For future reference, you have to indent code four spaces or tags gets stripped.

Comment: @NickLockwood can you please elaborate your solution !

Answer (score 7):

Don't use an iframe, just load the video directly in the webview (a webview is basically like a "native" iframe anyway):

```
NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@",video_ID];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```